# How is God the Father and God the Son and God the Holy Spirit the same?

Tags: faith

I don't get that God is three persons and not one it just doesn't make sense to me at all. How does one God become three persons? Like as in a 3 leafed clover?

Answer (score 2):

First, you ask a very good question.  Books have been written on this subject but I will try to answer this.  The Bible teaches that God is one.  I don't think anyone with biblical knowledge would dispute that ( Isaiah 44:6, John 5:44, 1 Corinthians 8:4).  The bible also teaches that Jesus Christ is God (John 1:1, 14,  John 20:28, Hebrews 1:8) and that the Holy Spirit is God (Acts 5:3-4, 1 Corinthians 2:10-11).

So the bible teaches God is one but in that oneness three personi, or persons, exist.  Do I completely understand that?  No, but I don't presume to understand everything about God.  We Christians use the term, Trinity, to describe the three persons within the Godhead.  "Trinity" isn't a biblical term.  It is not found in the Bible.  Trinity is a theological term that we use to describe a biblical truth.  I hope this helped you, Godbless. I tried to add a picture to help you.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please consider taking the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and seeing [How we are different to other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|0.8617).

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by John is good, however;  I hesitate to +1 his answer as it lacks so much that is known about the trinity.   The trinity, God in himself, is the central mystery of the Christian Faith, of all faiths really as there is only one.  The clover example like any other analogy, falls short of bringing us to an understanding of what God is.  I prefer h2o which has 3 forms, water , ice and steam, but even that falls short.  There simply is no analogy of that relationship that does e trinity justice with maybe the exception of the cross, which is God revealing himself to us by his works, which is the plan of salvation or the Devine economy.  Rejoice in what God has revealed to us. The Cross shows us on so many levels what the trinity is, that is a relationship that is based solely on self gift, the father completely giving himself to the son, and the son completely giving himself to the father, neither holding anything back. This relationship being so perfect and so strong constituted the Holy Spirit which like the father and the son has existed for all time.

When Christ gave himself for us on the cross, he gave every bit of himself, showing us by example what love is, what the Triune God is.  Total self gift, otherwise referred to as "Love".

If you are confused about the Trinity, well, welcome abourd the confusion train, you are not alone but you are in good company.